# Using a While Loop to update a field by 1 each time a value changes

Tags: loops, while-loop, sql-update

So I have a table that has two records that need to be one. I can identify them but I want to update them in groups (sort of like a scan update =1, then proceed, then some other field changes, increment the number by 1 and proceed.)

Example table:

```
IDEvent 1 2 3 4 5

Col1    1 1 0 1 0

Col2    a a b a b
```

So essentially, my outcome would look like this afterwards so that I can write a select and group by col1 to then group the two first records into one but leave non consecutive record alone. I tried while loops but I couldn't figure it out.

```
IDEvent   1 2 3 4 5

 Col1     1 1 0 2 0

 Col2     A A B A B
```

Comment: figured it out. will post answer once I'm allowed to answer my own question. essentially

Answer (score 0):

alter view PtypeGroup as

WITH q AS
(
  SELECT *,
         ROW_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY idsession, comment ORDER BY ideventrecord) AS rnd,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idsession ORDER BY ideventrecord) AS rn
  FROM [ratedeventssorted]
)
 SELECT min(ideventrecord) as IDEventRecord, idsession, min(distancestamp) as distancestamp, sum(length) as length, min(comment) as comment2, min(eventscorename) as firstptype, min(eventscoredescription) as Ptype2,
       MIN(ideventrecord) AS first_number,
       MAX(ideventrecord) AS last_number,
       comment
       ,COUNT(ideventrecord) AS numbers_count

```
   --into test
```

FROM q

where eventscorename IN ('Flex', 'Chpsl')
GROUP BY idsession,
         rnd - rn,
         comment